# pgfplots external file formatting

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Does any of you know know the standard formatting for `pgfplots` graphs taken from external files (and also file type accepted e.g. `txt`, `dat`) and what should go in the `\addplot` to have the data be taken from that exact file

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please be more specific. Does[TIKZ drawing vector field from external file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59729/124842) help?

Comment: I'm doing a program tha converts a .txt file in a standard format to be given to a specific pgf-plot

Comment: What is an "standard format"? Could you add a[MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: I have datas in this format 206,00,0,820 and it will be spliting into 206,00 as x-axis and 0,820 as y-axis

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of your data and your latex code. Is the first link related to your question, does it help?

Comment: Your question is quite broad. There are plenty of possibilities to provide data that PGFPlots can read. Best is you have a look at the [PGFPlots manual (v1.15) section 4.3.2](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=47). There all possibilities are listed.

Answer (score 6):

- Plain text files are the only thing supported I believe, but the file extension is whatever you like it to be, `.txt`, `.dat`, `.csv`, `.montypython`, whatever.
- The standard format is whitespace-delimited columns, in the sense that the default expected column delimiter is whitespace ("at least one tab or space", to quote the manual). However, you can specify a different separator with the `col sep` key, which can have these different options:

  ```
  col sep=space|tab|comma|colon|semicolon|braces|&|ampersand
  ```

  So if you have a text file looking like

  ```
  x y
  1 1
  2 3
  ```

  then you can do

  ```
  \addplot table {<filename including extension>};
  ```

  and you get a plot of y vs. x. `pgfplots` will, if not instructed otherwise, use the first column for the x-values, and the second for the y-values.

  If you have a comma separate file, i.e.

  ```
  x,y
  1,1
  2,3
  ```

  then you need to say

  ```
  \addplot table[col sep=comma] {<filename including extension>};
  ```
- If you have more than two columns, you select the columns you want for x and y with either `x=<column name>, y=<column name>`, or `x index=<number>, y index=<number>`. (You can of course use e.g. the name for `x`, and `index` for `y`, if you like.) So for example,

  ```
  \addplot table[x=x, y=y] {<filename including extension>};
  ```

  for the first example file shown above, where the column headings actually are `x` and `y`.

  If the first row contains just numbers, then `pgfplots` will not read it as column names, assuming instead that the file doesn't have a header row.

  - The `<column name>` is the text written in the first row, so `x` and y` for the above examples.
  - The `<number>` is the the column number, but note that the counting starts at zero, so to get the first column for `x` you do `x index=0`.

Example code, if that is of interest:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{A.dat}
0 0
1 1
2 2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{B.csv}
0,1
1,2
2,3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{C.montypython}
foo bar baz
0 2 3
1 3 4
2 4 5
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table {A.dat};
\addplot table[col sep=comma] {B.csv};
\addplot table[x=foo, y=bar] {C.montypython};
\addplot table[x index=0, y index=2] {C.montypython};

\legend{A,B,C1,C2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]