# Long labels when using pgfplottables

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

So I got some data that is mostly the same as displayed in the textfile `laerebok.txt`

```
Label, I ingen eller svært liten grad,  I liten grad,   I noen grad,    I stor grad,    I svært stor grad,  Ikke relevant
Forberede meg til nettmøter/forelesning,                                              15,   18, 11,  6,  7,  0
For å forberede meg til lab ekskursjon eller datalab,                                 14,    7,  4,  2,  5, 25
For å få en oversikt over deler av faget som ikke blir gjennomgått på forelesning,     9,    9, 18, 12,  9,  0
For å få tips til å gjøre innleveringer/obliger,                                       7,    4, 10, 11, 24,  1
For å få tips til å løse oppgaver (ikke innleveringer/obliger),                        6,    8, 11, 13, 16,  3
For å repetere lærestoff/forberede meg til eksamen,                                    5,    4, 12, 12, 24,  0
For å fordype meg i temaer jeg er interessert i,                                      14,   13, 15,  9,  4,  2
```

I want to display the data something like this

[image]

E.G a stacked bar plot. However, I am only able to produce the following

[image]

I got two problems I would like to fix

- I keep getting the error when using `æ ø å` in my table:

  ```
  Missing \edcsname inserted. 
  \T1\ae
  ```

  How can I fix this? I thought I already enabled these characters through `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?
- There is some issues with LaTeX complaining about too many columns, even though I specified column sep should be comma?

Any helps resolving these issues would be much obliged. The code for my attempt is attached below

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % usually not needed (loaded by default)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{filecontents*}{laerebok.txt}
Label, I ingen eller svAErt liten grad, I liten grad,   I noen grad,    I stor grad,    I svAErt stor grad, Ikke relevant
Forberede meg til nettmOOter/forelesning,                                              15,  18, 11,  6,  7,  0
For AA forberede meg til lab ekskursjon eller datalab,                                 14,   7,  4,  2,  5, 25
For AA fAA en oversikt over deler av faget som ikke blir gjennomgAAtt pAA forelesning,  9,   9, 18, 12,  9,  0
For AA fAA tips til AA gjOOre innleveringer/obliger,                                    7,   4, 10, 11, 24,  1
For AA fAA tips til AA lOOse oppgaver (ikke innleveringer/obliger),                     6,   8, 11, 13, 16,  3
For AA repetere lAErestoff/forberede meg til eksamen,                                   5,   4, 12, 12, 24,  0
For AA fordype meg i temaer jeg er interessert i,                                      14,  13, 15,  9,  4,  2
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\laeringsGraf}[1]{%
   %
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
              xbar stacked,   % Stacked horizontal bars
              xmin=0,         % Start x axis at 0
              ytick=data,     % Use as many tick labels as y coordinates
              yticklabels from table={#1}{Label}  % Get the labels from the Label column of the \datatable
  ]
  % "First" column against the data index
  \addplot [fill=cyan!0!green!100] table [col sep = comma,x={I ingen eller svAErt liten grad}, meta=Label,y expr=\coordindex] {#1};   
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20!green!80] table [col sep = comma,x={I liten grad}, meta=Label,y expr=\coordindex] {#1};
  \addplot [fill=cyan!40!green!60] table [col sep = comma,x={I noen grad}, meta=Label,y expr=\coordindex] {#1};
  \addplot [fill=cyan!60!green!40] table [col sep = comma,x={I stor grad}, meta=Label,y expr=\coordindex] {#1};
  \addplot [fill=cyan!80!green!20] table [col sep = comma,x={I svAErt stor grad}, meta=Label,y expr=\coordindex] {#1};
  \addplot [fill=cyan!100!green!0] table [col sep = comma,x={Ikke relevant}, meta=Label,y expr=\coordindex] {#1};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  %
}

\begin{document}

\laeringsGraf{laerebok.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with the special characters can be solved when using the respective `babel` language e.g. `\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}` (sorry but I wasn't sure if danish or norsk) together with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. You can change between the langauges with `\begin{otherlanguage}{...}`

Comment: You should probably use pgfplotstable instead of filecontents if you want it to be read by pgfplots.

Comment: @Steradiant I tried adding `babel` but it still complains about `T1\ae`. @John Kormylo, what do you mean? I followed this example to a T https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416476/pgfplots-external-file-formatting I got my data in external files. I just used filecontents here to create a MWE.

Comment: One problem is, that those characters are not anymore present in your MWE. Hence, if I copy the MWE I don't get an error regarding the special characters so I can't really reproduce it.

Comment: @Steradiant The original characters are included as the first part of my post. Simply replace the filecontents part with the text in the codeblock at the top. (Or replace AE with æ, OO with ø and AA with å)

Comment: Honestly, that's really a lot of work. That's why there should be an MWE. I just inserted the 3 special characters `æ ø å` after adding the babel and I get no error.

Comment: @Steradiant Does the following file work flawlessly for you? https://pastebin.com/6y3xNthy I've tried on multiple TeX distributions and all of them yield the same T1 error.

Comment: I've now just tried to put the text from filecontents into the document section as plain text and this worked fine for me. Hence, there is no problem with the special Norwegian characters for me. Regarding the plot, I'll have to have a closer look I've more time.