# Pgf - (hack?) jump mark

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Despite my readings (in the manual, or in the posts here), I did not find much on how to change the style of the `jump mark`, to have, for instance, an arrow.

**Edit : Is there a way to influence the behavior of `jump mark` ?**

The closest I found was this answer by Jake **but** [with quivers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59733/163874)

I'd like to get something like

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[samples=8]
\addplot+[jump mark left,domain=-5:5] {x*x};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All nodes in your graph are equidistant from each another, so you actually could make use of the `quiver` option, but omit the vertical part (or set it equal to zero):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[samples=8]
\addplot+[quiver={u=2}, -stealth, shorten >=10pt, domain=-5:5] {x*x};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This would result in the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). I'll wait a bit to validate it since I'd like (I edited my question to make it more clear) to know if/how we can directly influence the behavior of `jump mark`.

Comment: As far as I know, the whole plot is only one path, therefore, at least as far as I know, it is not that easy to add arrow heads at every section.

Comment: @JasperHbitcht Thank you. I accepted your answer Just for my information, do you know where I could find the defintion of `jump mark`?